# hide element with CSS without knowing their class or id as done here

Tags: css, blogger

visit this [webpage](http://brostyro.blogspot.com).

It is a blogger website without topmost navbar. We don't know the id of the navbar so how is it hidden?

I tried `margin-bottom` but it leaves extra space.

Comment: Which element do you want to hide?

Comment: I am fairly sure you are not allowed to do that on blogspot …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this:

```
body {
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

That's why the navbar is hidden. Remove it and navbar appears

Comment: you want to say if i add this property in my style sheet i can hide that navbar.

Comment: The bar has an id of `#navbar` by the way.

Comment: well just like that i want to ask how do you get properties of hidden elements,

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations you should not remove a question's tag, it can afèct the question

Comment: Properties of hidden elements? With Firebug!

Comment: I removed the CSS3 tag and kept the CSS one from the question because it's unrelated to CSS3

Comment: FireBug is an absolutely free tool